# How do you call a concrete water catching thing under outdoor water tap?

Tags: concrete, outdoor

How do you call this concrete thing under the tap on pic #1? Does it come prefabricated or is it made in place and, if so, how? Does it require connection to drainage system?

I just need something under my outdoor tap so whatever water gets out when say water hose is disconnected is caught somewhere and doesn't simply flow downhill. See pic #2. I don't really want to connect it to drainage system as it is obviously much more work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: a mosquito farm? yuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is a "**catch basin**". That one is particularly handsome. it's probably an antique. That one doesn't seem to be draining. In frost prone areas draining would be essential to prevent cracking from it freezing. I can imagine mosquito larvae would be another good reason to allow it to drain. Where water is precious, neither one of those reasons rise above saving every drop.

I wanted to add that modern versions of this type of catch basin generally have grilles on top which prevent debris from falling in, but also children or your drunken uncle's foot. Although, if you had farm animals about, they would appreciate easy access.

Answer (score 3):

I would call it a "basin".

A "catch basin" often refers to something else:  A [box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/NDS-12-in-x-12-in-Catch-Basin-2-Opening-Kit-1200BKIT/100377423) that pipe(s) drain into, and another pipe drains out of.  The bottom of the box is lower than the outlet pipe.  Sediment can settle in the catch basin, and not flow into the outlet pipe.

If you bought a shallow concrete sink basin or bird bath basin that drained into a hose, you could drain the basin with only a modest amount of work.  Route a hose from the basin's drain to a place you want to water.  (You could put the hose 4 - 12 inches underground, to improve æsthetics and avoid tripping hazards.)  At the end of the hose, attach drip irrigation tubing.  Unfortunately, [Netafim-style emitters](http://www.netafimusa.com/landscape/products/driplines/techline-cv/) would not work in this application, because they need a 2 psi pressure differential to emit water.

Comment: Not wishing to seem argumentative, the term “catch basin” pre-dates the current use to describe storm and irrigation drains. Springs and well pumps as well as fountains were and are still fitted with catch basins not to trap trash but to accumulate water for dippers or buckets.